# Using filesort to sort by datetime column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, performance, filesort

I have a table Cars with datetime (DATE) and bit (PUBLIC).

Now i would like to take rows ordered by DATE and with PUBLIC = 1 so i use:

```
select
  c.*
from
  Cars c
WHERE 
   c.PUBLIC = 1
ORDER BY 
   DATE DESC
```

But unfortunately when I use explain to see what is going on I have this:

```
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL     IDX_PUBLIC,DATE     NULL    NULL    NULL    103     Using where; Using filesort
```

And it takes 0,3 ms to take this data while I have only 100 rows. Is there any other way to disable filesort?

If i goes to indexes I have index on (PUBLIC, DATE) not unique.

Table def:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Cars` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `PUBLIC` binary(1) NOT NULL default '0'
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `IDX_PUBLIC` (`PUBLIC`),
  KEY `DATE` (`PUBLIC`,`DATE`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT=186 ;
```

Comment: Could you please post your table's definition? Just run `SHOW CREATE TABLE Cars`

Comment: 300 microseconds for 100 rows?  3 microseconds per row?  That performance is not rotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a composite index on `(public, date)`

This way, `MySQL` will filter on `public` and sort on `date`.

From your `EXPLAIN` I see that you don't have a composite index on `(public, date)`.

Instead you have two different indexes on `public` and on `date`. At least, that's what their names `IDX_PUBLIC` and `DATE` tell.

**Update:**

You `public` column is not a `BIT`, it's a `BINARY(1)`. It's a character type and uses character comparison.

When comparing integers to characters, `MySQL` converts the latter to the former, not vice versa.

These queries return different results:

```
CREATE TABLE t_binary (val BINARY(2) NOT NULL);

INSERT
INTO    t_binary
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(10);

SELECT  *
FROM    t_binary
WHERE   val <= 10;

---
1
2
3
10

SELECT  *
FROM    t_binary
WHERE   val <= '10';
---
1
10
```

Either change your `public` column to be a `bit` or rewrite your query as this:

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    Cars c
WHERE   c.PUBLIC = '1'
ORDER BY 
        DATE DESC
```

, i. e. compare characters with characters, not integers.

Comment: I have one index on (PUBLIC) and second one is composite(PUBLIC, DATE). Should I remove first one?

Comment: The second one should be used anyway. Could you please post the table's definition?

Comment: No problem. I've added tab def

Answer (score 1):

If you are ordering by date, a sort will be required.  If there isn't an index by date, then a filesort will be used.  The only way to get rid of that would be to either add an index on date or not do the order by.

Also, a filesort does not always imply that the file will be sorted on disk.  It could be sorting it in memory if the table is small enough or the sort buffer is large enough.  It just means that the table itself has to be sorted.

Looks like you have an index on date already, and since you are using PUBLIC in your where clause, MySQL should be able to use that index.  However, the optimizer may have decided that since you have so few rows it isn't worth bothering with the index.  Try adding 10,000 or so rows to the table, re-analyze it, and see if that changes the plan.