# order by causes filesort

Tags: mysql, datetime, innodb, filesort

I still have following problem

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT
  `item`.`id`,
  `item`.`timestamp`,
  `item`.`label`
  FROM
  item
WHERE
  item.dataTypeId=30
GROUP BY
  item.id
ORDER BY
  item.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0,6;
```

**Id & timestamp** is a primary key pair (mediumint+datetime)
**dataTypeId** is a foreign key (mediumint)
table is created as **InnoDb**

There can be more records with same id and different timestamp (versions of same item). This is the **reason for group by**.

I read for example this one: [similar topic on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471243/using-filesort-to-sort-by-datetime-column-in-mysql)

but it didnt solve my problem.

I've tried to create following indexes:

1. index on (dataTypeId, id, timestamp) - in that order
2. index on (dataTypeId, timestamp) - in that order
3. index on id
4. index on timestamp

the last two is a little piece of desperation

i think i must miss something basic -
but really do no know what.
Do not expect the solution (it would be nice :) just kick me the right way :)

sort_buffer_size is now 4194288

**edit:**
explain - no indexes

```
"1" "SIMPLE"    "item"  "ref"   "FK_dataTypeId" "FK_dataTypeId" "4" "const" "5608"  "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
```

explain with indexes created

```
"1" "SIMPLE"    "item"  "ref"   "FK_udssDataItem_1,testIndexType,testIndexTypeTimestamp,testIndexTypeIdTime"    "FK_udssDataItem_1" "4" "const" "5632"  "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
```

Comment: file sort does not mean slow, please throw in the **EXPLAIN** query results

Comment: the query accross 5000 row takes 2seconds, I've simplified my original query to minimum size - and trying step-by-step except one possible reason after another. The only "hot point" in EXPLAIN is the one with "filesort". Another rows operate via indexes with small count of rows ...

Comment: Firstly, you are GROUPing by id, but you are ordering by timestamp... that does not make logical sense. You should likely be ordering by some aggregate function (AVG/MAX/MIN) on the timestamp.

Comment: well yes, but the order column may differ - there are more - release date time, last update date time etc. this should be just an example.

Comment: i mean - all the columns are datetime - i am not sure whether - 1) i have bad indexes, 2) bad configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with your query. When you do the "group by id", you may have different timestamps for the same id and have not specified which one to use (Min(), max() etc) a similar problem occurs with the "label" field.

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html

So you need agregate functions on timestamp and label otherwise the values returned may be unpredictable.

As you are grouping by id and the sorting by timestamp, so MySQL extracts one timestamp per group so an index doesn't really help much. You may not be able to get rid of the filesort with this query.

Comment: OMG I am soooo beginner when i see what i wrote a then all the answers. I also did not know that filesort does not necessary mean slow. So that is why I suspected this part of query first. Thanks for your advice & linked article.

Answer (score 1):

So your question is "How to avoid filesort on your query" ?
In which case, to get MySQL to do an index sort you need to have all of the columns in your index in your where clause.

With the id,timestamp primary key you have to

```
where id = myid and item.timestamp between (t1,t2)
```

Also beware of open-ended ranges (and timestamp < now() )

I'm not sure what datatypeID is, but if thats your only condition, then adding an index on just that column should also suggest an index sort. but you might have to create the index on (timestamp,datatypeID)  ...in that order... instead.

Comment: As @ajreal mentioned, a filesort is not always bad though. I spent a lot of time trying to get rid of a filesort recently only to have it make hardly any difference in the end.
If you've got the memory to spare , an easy Alternative is to just softlink your /tmp directory to /dev/shm, that way a file sort is essentially a memory sort.

Comment: yes, that should be my question. But still i put all the columns in order statement into the index - still filesorting. Then i put all the columns in where and order statement (filesort). Then tried other combination (as i wrote).